# Wireless hard drive alternative using external HD and router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hard-drive, router, external-hard-drive

My friend is going to china for a year and needs to have a large storage device to access lots of movies, music etc... **from his iPad**.

Wireless harddrives are available such as [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Seagate-Wireless-Mobile-Device-Storage/dp/B00AZIRNP2/ref=sr_1_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1374578654&sr=1-2&keywords=wireless%20hard%20drive) one, they seem great but the problem is they have a pretty high price tag. I was thinking, would it be possible to get a router then just plug the external HD into it and share it over the WiFi network, then use an app on the iPad to access the drive?

Comment: Just get a router that has a USB port, this will allow any USB storage device, to become a NAS. You can also get non-wireless NAS devices for much cheaper.  I personally would not trust a wireless network in China unless I used a very long passphrase.

Comment: And this will work without an internet connection? Just the router and the HD eg http://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-Increased-High-speed-Connection-F5D8235uk4/dp/B001IL4ZA6/ref=sr_1_7?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1374579897&sr=1-7&keywords=router+usb+port and http://www.amazon.co.uk/Intenso-6002510-Station-5400rpm-External/dp/B0034G51WY/ref=sr_1_24?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1374579995&sr=1-24&keywords=500gb+external+hd

Comment: You should be able to connect to a router without an internet connection. The reason the linked product is so expensive is because it broadcasts its own wireless network, so its basically a router, and can function without an external internet connection. My suggestion is not guaranteed to work with an iPad because there won't be a dedecated application to stream the content, my suggestion, might require an iOS application or evne a PC to implement